# How to get a better Lucene/Solr score if word queried was at the beginning of the indexed field?

Tags: solr, lucene

I read at some point something explaining what to do to have Lucene/Solr give a better score if my queried word was found at the beginning of the description I indexed. Cannot find it anymore on the net. Anybody has the links handy ? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that the first few words of the given text matters more than the rest? I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101478/sunspot-boost-records-where-matches-occur-early-in-the-text/9108602#9108602 . And personally, I dont recall such a link coming up on any questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Payloads could help you do that. Actually, payloads let you give an arbitrary boost to any token of your token stream, so you can boost depending on anything:

- the position in the stream,
- the font weight,
- whether the token contains capital letters,
- ...

You can read more about payloads in this [nice post from Grant Ingersoll](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/).