# Lucene: How to rank documents according to the position in document

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Im looking at using lucene to add search to a product database.

Given a query "red hat"

and the products given by descriptions

[0] "red hat linux advanced server with free training"

[1] "a big box of red hat linux with red hat linux written on the label"

Is it possible to write the lucene query so that terms matched at the start of the description are given more weight to those that match further towards the end.

Answer (score 0):

This will require some work, but you can achieve this using payloads. See answers to this very similar question:

[How to get a better Lucene/Solr score if word queried was at the beginning of the indexed field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490389/how-to-get-a-better-lucene-solr-score-if-word-querried-was-at-the-beginning-of-t/9496398#9496398)